# Gson changes key

Tags: android, arrays, json, gson

I have a custom list and I am using Gson to convert to jsonArray.

The problem is that if I am using the debug version apk, it is working perfectly, but if I am using the release version apk, the keys change.

Example:

```
Debug version -> "name", "Mary"
Release version -> "a", "Mary"
```

All keys change to "a, b, c..."

I have proguard in both versions.

My code:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
JsonArray jsonArray = gson.toJsonTree(myCustomList).getAsJsonArray();
```

Gradle code:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        debuggable true
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

    }
    debug {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

proguard code:

```
-dontwarn okhttp3.**
-dontwarn okio.**

##---------------Begin: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
# Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with fields. Proguard
# removes such information by default, so configure it to keep all of it.
-keepattributes Signature

# For using GSON @Expose annotation
-keepattributes *Annotation*

# Gson specific classes
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
#-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }

# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
-keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { *; }

# Prevent proguard from stripping interface information from TypeAdapterFactory,
# JsonSerializer, JsonDeserializer instances (so they can be used in @JsonAdapter)
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonSerializer
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer
```

I added `-keep class yourPackageName.data.model.** { *; }`  with my package name but I got the same problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess minify not enabled for your debug builds. So you need to keep your model classes when obfuscation happens. This example intents to keep all the model class inside the specified package `-keep class yourPackageName.data.model.** { *; }`

Comment: But I am using proguard in Debug version too

Comment: Both too, really it is strange, I am going to post the proguard settings

Comment: It can't be. Because it should of rename the field or methods on your debug builds too

Comment: I added more details

Comment: `-keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { *; }` this is wrong package. This should be your package name or wherever you put your model classes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149300/discussion-between-dahnark-and-santalu).

Answer (score 3):

Keep your member class:

```
class Name{

 @SerializedName("fNmae")

   private String fNmae;

}


-keepclassmembers class com.integration.Name{
private *;
}
```